# Manage and include Handlebars.js files with symfony 2.1 and Assetic

Tags: symfony-2.1, handlebars.js, assetic

I want to exclude my handlebars.js template from my twig files.

So I created a new directory in the `public` folder named `hbs` where I placed all my handlebar templates. How do I tell assetic to render those templates and wrap it with the script tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need AsseticBundle 2.1.2 or later. Besides that, you need to do three things:

1. Install the handlebars compiler
2. Configure an assetic filter to compile your handlebars templates
3. Include the templates in your twig template.

**Installing the compiler**

Follow the [instructions on the handlebars website](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html). Or, shorter:

```
npm install handlebars -g
```

**Configuring the filter**

Add this to your config file:

```
assetic:
    filters:
        handlebars:
             apply_to: "\.handlebars$"
```

This will tell assetic to apply the handlebars filter to all files ending in ".handlebars", effectively turning them into a compiled handlebars template. You can adjust the setting to whatever ending you prefer.

You may need to tell assetic where your handlebars compiler resides if it isn't in the default location (/usr/bin/handlebars). Use the "bin" setting of the handlebars filter for that. For example, if you have installed it in a subdirectory of your project (by using npm without the -g option), your config 
might look like this:

```
assetic:
    filters:
        handlebars:
             apply_to: "\.handlebars$"
             bin: node_modules/handlebars/bin/handlebars
```

**Reference in Twig template**

Add a new reference in your twig template similar to how you would include javascript files:

```
{% javascripts
    '@MyBundle/Resources/public/hbs/*.handlebars'

        output='assets/my-handlebars-templates.js'
        %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>  
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Then you can use the templates in your project. They are stored in Handlebars.templates[templatename] with "template-name" being the filename of your template excluding ".handlebars".

Hope that helps...

Comment: If your node.js executable is in a different location than `/usr/bin/node` (for example in `/usr/local/bin/node` if you installed it on Mac OS X via the offical installer), you need to add `node:/path/to/node` to the `handlebars` assetic filter configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You may put right path to handlebars in bin. Following worked for me.

```
assetic:
    filters:
        handlebars:
            apply_to: "\.handlebars"
            bin: /usr/local/bin/handlebars
```

Get the right location of handlebars using

```
which handlebars
```